# How do I use not.toBeResolved() in a jasmine test?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I want to test that a promise does not resolve in jasmine. It appears that I might be able to use [`not.toBeResolved()`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/4.3/async-matchers.html), but when I do I get a timeout error:

```
it('should not resolve', async () => {
  const unresolvablePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {});
  await expectAsync(unresolvablePromise).not.toBeResolved();
});
```

`Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)`

I expected this would be the idea of `not.toBeResolved` - that if the promise hadn't resolved in the timeout period the test would pass.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing `.not.toBeResolved` is a catch 22 where it never resolves because it is awaiting for the promise and then asserting it.

I would do something like this:

```
// add the done callback
it('should not resolve', (done) => {
  // assign a variable to determine if the promise was resolved
  let promiseResolved = false;
  const unresolvablePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {});
  // call Jasmine fail if it does resolve thereby failing the test
  // and update the variable to true
  unresolvablePromise.then(() => { 
    promiseResolved = true;
    fail(); 
  });
  // 500ms (ample time for the promise to resolve), expect the variable to be false
  // and call done
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(promiseResolved).toBeFalse();
    done();
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, though I was hoping for a cleaner solution - I already have one which uses `waitForAsync` and `expect.nothing()` and thought `.not.toBeResolved` might simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the promise to be in a pending state, use:

```
await expectAsync(promise).toBePending();
```

https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.7/async-matchers.html#toBePending